# delete[] doesn't free memory according to Valgrind

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, valgrind, destructor

I have a class `unix_socket` that has a `double*` as an attribute, and allocates memory with `new` in its constructor:

```
class unix_socket::unix_socket(){
    //...
    array_recvd=new double[10];
    //...
}
```

and consequently I am using `delete[]` in its destructor in order to free the memory:

```
unix_socket::~unix_socket(){
    //..
    delete[] array_recvd;
    //...
}
```

However, when using `Valgrind` to check for memory leaks in the program, the memory used by the array isn't freed:

```
==4683== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4683==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==4683==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 648 bytes allocated
==4683== 
==4683== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==4683== Checked 188,184 bytes
==4683== 
==4683== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==4683==    at 0x4C2BBA4: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==4683==    by 0x406503: unix_socket::unix_socket() (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/client)
==4683==    by 0x402355: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/client)
==4683== 
==4683== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4683==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4683==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4683==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4683==    still reachable: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==4683==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I'm sure this leak is due to the <s>`vector_recvd`</s> `array_recvd`, since it is only present when I have it as an attribute. What exactly am I doing wrong? How would I free the memory allocated by the array of doubles?

**EDIT**: So this is the `main.cpp` I'm using to replicate this issue:

```
int main () {

  unix_socket client;    
  client.initSocket(DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH,CLIENT_MODE);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
    client.sendVectorXd(VectorXd::Ones(30));
  }

  client.closeSocket();    
  return 0;
}
```

Probably relevant: this issue is only present when the socket connection is refused (no server waiting for the client).

**EDIT 2**: So I've found the problem, and it was indeed in `initSocket()`. If connecting to a socket server somehow failed (as was the case), I had `exit(1)`:

```
if (connect(client_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
}
```

I assumed that calling `exit()` would call the destructors, I see now that's not the case.

Comment: Are you sure you destructed all instances of `unix_socket`?

Comment: Also, if `array_recvd` is always an array of 10 double's, then you could declare that data member as an array directly and get rid of the burden to delete it.

Comment: You can be more sure about what is leaking by looking at the file and line number of the unmatched `new[]`: `vg_replace_malloc.c:363`.  And you code snippets say `array_recvd`, but your commentary says `vector_recvd`.

Comment: How and where is the `unix_socket` in question constructed? That valgrind thinks it's still reachable suggests the object has not been destroyed at all.

Comment: Are you sure there is memory leak as `definitely lost is 0`?

Comment: Make a simple printf debugging: one cout for allocation with the address, one for deallocation, then compare. I am quite sure you will find the same results

Comment: what does 'client.initSocket' do ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH How exactly would I do that?